# Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type 'this'

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types, interface

**IUser interface:**

```
interface IUser {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  crypto: string;
}
```

**Class User:**

```
class User implements IUser {
  private crypto$: string;
  constructor(public username: string, public email: string, crypto: string) {
    this.crypto$ = crypto;
  }

  public get crypto(): string {
    return this.crypto$;
  }

  updateUser<T extends Partial<Omit<IUser, "crypto">>>(newUserProps: T) {
    Object.keys(newUserProps).forEach((key) => {
      const propKey = key as keyof T;
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(propKey)) {
        this[propKey] = newUserProps[propKey];
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I get this error: [image: error code]

**PS: when I use type assertion like this `(this as any)[propKey]` the error dissapears, but I don't want to use the `any` type**

*Thank You for your help!*

Comment: You're already asserting `as keyof T` so you might as well go further and do something like `as (keyof T & keyof this)`.  For example, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLAGaW) (which cuts out the seemingly useless generic `T` type here) might do what you want.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, @jcalz! I did exactly what's written in the playground provided, but i still get an error saying: 
 "Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Comment: I did an if check: ```if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) && newUserProps[key] !== undefined) {
        this[key] = newUserProps[key];
      }
``` but still gives me the same error

Comment: But you didn't do exactly what's written in the playground; you changed it, so different things happened.  Is the scope of the question expanding to include different ways of doing null checks?  I'd like to keep things confined to the question as asked, and have it be a single well defined question, not multiple.  Shall I answer with the code as written in the playground? Or do you want to [edit] the question to make it clear that you're asking about something else?

Comment: I just want a solution to the main problem. And yes I did exactly what's in the playground but still didn't work

Comment: ‍♂️ I don't know what to tell you, sorry.  Since [the playground](https://tsplay.dev/NrEO0w) clearly works by itself, whatever issue you're having has to be caused by a *difference* between them, somewhere. If you can demonstrate the difference by [edit]ing to provide a [mre] where my code is visibly seen to stop working, maybe I can look at it again. Otherwise I think I've exhausted my ability to diagnose your issue remotely and I'll disengage to give others a chance to help and reduce noise.  Good luck!